# Как правильно организовать общение клиент-сервер?

Tags: c#, сеть, сокеты

Здравствуйте! Я делаю так, сначала посылаю 2 байта, к примеру 145 и 85 (по ним определяется начало сообщения). Затем посылаю 4 байта (которые указывают длину сообщения). Затем идет само сообщение в формате JSON. Но иногда происходит так, что передача сбивается и на другой стороне принимаются левые данные. Правильна ли такая передача данных? Или нужно использовать какую-то другую?

Comment: Какой протокол вы используете? Почему бы не воспользоваться чем то высокоуровневым типа WCF + http binding?

Comment: Я сериализовываю пересылаемые данные в JSON и указываю ID пакета. А данные пересылаю по своему протоколу, который описал выше. Но что-то он со сбоями работает, не могу понять почему

Comment: я вижу что вы делаете, я спрашиваю зачем вы это делаете? Какую задачу решаете? Почему именно своим протоколом?

Comment: Потому что я планирую общаться не только между C# приложениями.

Comment: Есть ли какие-то готовые высокоуровневые кроссплатформенные сетевые библиотеки? Я просто решил понять как работает сеть

Comment: Стандартный способ пересылки. Если сообщение всегда начинается с 2 + 4 байт, используется TCP, а не UDP протокол, используется один и тот же порядок байт на клиенте и сервере, то проблем, при правильной реализации, не будет. Вы же отдаете себе отчет, что количество отправленных и принятых TCP пакетов может не совпадать? Пакеты могут в канале как разбиваться, так и склеиваться. Гарантируется только, что получатель получит все байты, отосланный отправителем в том же порядке. Или получит ошибку

Comment: Ну, например, если вы хотите общаться по HTTP протоколу, то по идее без разницы, что на клиенте и что на сервере.